# After LVM/DRBD resize df is reporting incorrect information

Tags: debian, xen, disk-space-utilization, drbd

I have a Debian Xen DomU which has a DRBD mounted partition. I needed to resize this partition from 46G to 50G. I did the following:

- Stopped DRBD on the secondary node: `/etc/init.d/drbd stop`
- Increased the underlying LVM dist to 50 GB: `lvresize -L 50G /lvm/device`
- Started DRBD again and waited for the disk to sync: `/etc/init.d/drbd start`
- Switched Primaries. And performed the same on the other node.
- Stopped drbd on the now secondary DRBD node: `/etc/init.d/drbd stop`
- Increased the underlying LVM: `lvresize -L 50G /lvm/device`
- Started DRBD again and waited for the disk to sync: `/etc/init.d/drbd
  start`
- On both nodes issued: `drbdadm resize drbd-device`
- On the primary node issued a: `resize2fs /dev/drbd0`

I get this response:

```
$ resize2fs 1.40-WIP (14-Nov-2006)
The filesystem is already 12058624 blocks long.  Nothing to do!
```

Using fdisk, both the drbd0 and the sda device drbd is using report the size of the device as 49392123904. Which is consistent with what resize2fs is saying. (12058624x4096 [blocksize]).

My issue is that `df` isn't reporting the change to the disk size.

```
$ df -B 4096
/dev/drbd0            11869420  11155652    110968 100% /data
```

I have done this process before and had no issues. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: How was it mounted?

Also can you try df with
--sync
not sure what that does but if it is there maybe there is a reason!

Also what does fdisk say?

Comment: This all sounds right.  Does `lvs` report the expected size?

Comment: perhaps remounting the partition might help?

Comment: I never figured this out.

 * LVS was reporting the correct size of 50G.
 * Unmounting and remounting the partition didn't help.
 * Full reboot of these DomU's also didn't solve the issue.

It felt quite buggy that this wasn't working right and we were due for a hardware upgrade so I have since replaced these with 2 new CentOS machines and this is no longer an issue for me. I will however leave this question open in case someone else has similar issues.

Answer (score 2):

This guy wrote a nice howto about it:

http://theitdepartment.wordpress.com/2008/05/30/howto-resize-a-xen-drbd-lvm-vbd/

Comment: Does following the steps in that howto actually address the issue raised in the question?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to fiddle with secondary/primary roles.
Just do:
1. LVM resize on both sides
2. On the primary side: drbdadm resize RESOURCE (this will also update the meta-device)

Looking at /proc/drbd should show you a resync of the new portion in progress.
If this is not the case try "drbdadm adjust RESOURCE" on both sides.

Now resize the unmounted file-system using the primary side /dev/drbd/by-res/RESOURCE